# How do I prevent the "appspot.com" of my App Engine app?

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, dns

I have a custom domain added that I added to App Engine. For example, let's say my custom domain is "example.com".
My app is served with Node.js, and I when I deploy my app through App Engine, it gives me this address to access to it:

"example.appspot.com".

How do I prevent this? I want to serve my app only on "example.com".

**SOLVED:** I'm using this middleware to prevent those hostnames and it works, at least for what I kind of wanted:

```
var redirect = function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.hostname.search('appspot') !== -1) {
        res.redirect(301, 'https://www.example.com');
        next();
    }
    next();
};

app.use(redirect);
```

Comment: Prevent what? Remove the domain `example.appspot.com`? Prevent access using the domain `exmple.appspot.com`? Redirect visitors to `www.example.com`? Edit your question with details on what you are asking.

Comment: sorry, I just edited.

Comment: Code your app to check the HTTP Host request header based on the domain name and then respond accordingly with a redirect specifying an HTTP Location header in the response.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Location

Comment: For example use this command to see how the Location header is used: `curl -i http://www.jhanley.com`

Comment: Possibly of interest: comments to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57545133/disabling-version-specific-urls-in-google-appengine/57545687#57545687

Comment: Before choosing your strategy, read @DanCornilescu answer plus the comments. You probably do not want to drop/redirect the `appspot.com` domain completely.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to make that work with the 301 relocate, not so familiar with it but will try to do.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60883838/11392389